# Problema para borrar un registro de una tabla usando ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

me acabo de encontrar con el siguiente problema que como bien dice el titulo  del post no puedo borrar una fila de una tabla en mysql usando ajax y jquery.

Adjunto parte del código para que puedan ver  de que se trata y ayudarme a encontrar el error.

```js
function eliminarObraSocialPaciente(id, idPaciente){
    //$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#eliminar").click();
    alertify.confirm('¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar la obra social del paciente?', function(respuesta){
        if(respuesta){
          var idObraSocial = id.toString();
                $.ajax({
       "url": "lib/gestion/paciente/eliminar_obraSocialPaciente.php",
       "type": "POST",
       "dataType": "text",
       "data": {"parametro": idObraSocial}
       })
       .done(function(data) {
        alertify.alert("Se ha eliminado con exito la obra social del paciente seleccionado.");
     //window.location.href="files/paciente_modificar.php?&id="+idPaciente;
       })
       .fail(function() {
           alert("Error al eliminar la obra social del paciente seleccionado");
       }); 
            }
        }); 

}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.2/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-1 form-group"></div><div class="col-md-3 form-group">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textAseguradorMedico" class="control-label text-muted">Asegurador Medico</label>
        <input id="textAseguradorMedico" class="form-control input-sm" name="textAseguradorMedico" value="Prepaga" type="text">
       </div>
       </div><div class="col-md-2 form-group">
       <label for="textNombreObraSocial" class="control-label text-muted">Nombre</label>
       <input id="textNombreObraSocial" class="form-control input-sm" name="textNombreObraSocial" value="Medife" type="text">
      </div><div class="col-md-2 form-group">
       <label for="textPlanObraSocial" class="control-label text-muted">Plan Obra social</label>
       <input id="textPlanObraSocial" class="form-control input-sm" value="oro" type="text">
      </div><div class="col-md-2 form-group">
       <label for="textFechaVencimiento" class="control-label text-muted">Fecha Vencimiento</label>
       <input id="textFechaVencimiento" class="form-control input-sm" name="textFechaVencimiento" value="31/01/2019" type="text">
      </div><div class="col-md-2  form-group">
          <h1></h1>
          <a href="javaScript:eliminarObraSocialPaciente(16, 39)">
          <button id="buttonEliminar" type="button" name="eliminar" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-sm" style="margin-top: 2px; padding-top: 4px; top: 3px;padding-bottom: 5px;"></button></a>
      </div>
```

Adjunto el código del archivo "eliminar_obraSocialPaciente.php"

```
<?php
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"parametro");
echo $id;
require_once '../../../files/clases/Conexion.php';
$operacion = false;
$conexion = Conexion::establecer();
if(!$conexion->connect_error){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Paciente_por_ObraSocial WHERE Paciente_por_ObraSocial.id_Paciente_ObraSocial = ".$id."";
    echo $sql;
    if($conexion->query($sql)){
        if($conexion->affected_rows == 1){
            $operacion = true;
        }else echo 'No se encontraron coincidencia';
    else echo $conexion->error;
    $conexion->close();
}
```

?>

Creería que el error se debe a que no se esta enviando la id correctamente para que se ejecute la consulta mysql. Porque de echo se esta devolviendo el callback de éxito ".done(funtion(data)" al ejecutar la función "eliminar obraSocialPaciente(id, idPaciente)".

Gracias por su atención.

Espero respuesta positivas

Saludos.!

Answer (score 0):

para un mejor manejo de mensajes usa json_encode en tu script php.
ya con esto tu decides que resultados regresar en el arreglo.

ejemplo:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$msg="";
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"parametro");
$msg.= $id;
require_once '../../../files/clases/Conexion.php';
$operacion = false;
$conexion = Conexion::establecer();
if(!$conexion->connect_error){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Paciente_por_ObraSocial WHERE Paciente_por_ObraSocial.id_Paciente_ObraSocial = ".$id."";
    $msg=$sql;
    if($conexion->query($sql)){
        if($conexion->affected_rows == 1){
            $operacion = true;
        }else $msg.='No se encontraron coincidencia';
    else $msg.=$conexion->error;
    $conexion->close();
}
echo json_encode(array('msg' => $msg));
```

y en tu ajax

```
$.ajax({
                "url": "lib/gestion/paciente/eliminar_obraSocialPaciente.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                "data": {"parametro": idObraSocial}
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    alertify.alert(data.msg);
                    //window.location.href="files/paciente_modificar.php?&id="+idPaciente;
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert("Error al eliminar la obra social del paciente seleccionado");
                });
```